# Relay Commands Command Parameter

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, controltemplate, relaycommand

I am trying to work with the MVVM principles within a small WPF project using C#.
I have a `ListBox` that is populated with `CheckBox`es created through binding back to the ViewModel. I also have a command bound to the `CheckBox`es and wish to pass the `CheckBox`es `Content` as a `CommandParameter`. I was looking for something like this:

```
<Binding ElementName="" Path="Content"/>
```

Unfortunately, because the `CheckBox`es are created through a binding I don’t have the element name.

The code for `ListBox` / `ListBoxItem` `Style` is this:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <CheckBox Command="{Binding SelectedItemCommand, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource comd}}">
                                <CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource cv}">
                                        <Binding ElementName="" Path="Content"/>
                                    <Binding ElementName="" Path="IsChecked"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                                <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And its implementation is:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxListStyle}" Name="lstProducts" ItemsSource="{Binding stampInfo, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource vmStamp}}" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Country" >
</ListBox>
```

Ultimately my goal is to be able to display the text `Content`s (Countries in this case) of all the selected items  in a text box were each country is separated by a comma. The only thing I am currently missing is the `Country`.

Comment: Can yout show the code for your `CheckBox`es where the binding is used?

Comment: @thatguy. Thank you for your response and I have amended the question to include the requested binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not create a `ControlTemplate` for `ListBoxItem` when you really want to display your *data items* differently, use a `DataTemplate` instead, that is exactly its purpose. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Remove the `DisplayMemberPath` from the `ListBox`, as you cannot use both use a path and a custom `DataTemplate` at the same time. You would only set this path, if there was no `DataTemplate`, but you wanted to specify a concrete property or property path to display.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1"
         Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxListStyle}" Name="lstProducts"
         ItemsSource="{Binding stampInfo, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource vmStamp}}"/>
```

Replace the `ControlTemplate` with a `DataTemplate` as `ItemTemplate`. Then bind the `Content` and `CommandParameter` to the property `Country`. The data context is automatically set to the corresponding item in the bound collection of data items. The `IsChecked` property can be bound using a `RelativeSource`, which is the `CheckBox` itself.

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
   <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple"></Setter>
   <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
      <Setter.Value>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
         </Style>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
         <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Country}"
                      Command="{Binding SelectedItemCommand, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource comd}}">
                <CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource cv}">
                        <Binding Path="Country"/>
                        <Binding Path="IsChecked" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </CheckBox.CommandParameter>
            </CheckBox>
         </DataTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

A different option would be to create data items with a property that can be bound to the `IsChecked` property of `CheckBox`. Then you could act in the setter of the data item or on e.g. a button click that executes a command, which filters the bound collection in your view model for checked items.

Comment: Excellent thankyou. Your assistance and solution is very much appreciated.